# How to test SingleLiveEvent<Void> variable?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have a `SingleLiveEvent<Void>` variable. On getting response from api I am making it post. My callback is called and a popup is shown.
My question is how will I write a test case for checking, is my popup shown or not.

Live Event:

```
private SingleLiveEvent<Void> onAccountOverDrawn = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
```

On success response I am calling:

```
onAccountOverDrawn.post();
```

In my fragment I am registering it as

```
viewModel.getOnAccountOverDrawn().observe(this, aVoid -> onAccountOverDrawn());
```

and in `onAccountOverDrawn()` I am just showing a popup.

So how will I write a test case for this scenario?

Current test case:

```
@Test
public void updateApplicationStatus_AccountOverdrawn() {
    viewModel.updateApplicationStatus("AMOUNT_PENDING");

    assertNotNull(viewModel.getOnAccountOverDrawn()); //this line is of no use. Need to change this.
}
```

Comment: so you want to test if the SingleLiveEvent has been observed or not?

Comment: As a side note: using `SingleLiveEvent` is not recommended. See this post for better alternative: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem like this:

1. Get LiveData and subscribe our mock-observer to it.
2. Call the method that should change the LiveData inside the ViewModel.
3. Check that our mock-observer received the updated data.
4. Check that there were no more changes of this mock-observer.
5. Check that if we re-subscribe this mock-observer on the same LiveData then we do not receive data

See code below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeFeatureViewModelTest {

    private SomeFeatureViewModel mSomeFeatureViewModel;

    // Rule for help testing. Just trust me you need it :)
    @Rule
    public InstantTaskExecutorRule mRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @Mock
    private Observer<Void> mOnClickButtonEventObserver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mSomeFeatureViewModel = new SomeFeatureViewModel();
    }

    @Test
    public void clickOnNextScreenButton() {

        // get LiveData and subscribe our observer to it:
        mSomeFeatureViewModel.getOnClickButtonEvent().observeForever(mOnClickButtonEventObserver);

        // call the method that should change the LiveData inside the ViewModel:
        mSomeFeatureViewModel.clickOnNextScreenButton();

        // check that our observer received the updated data:
        verify(mOnClickButtonEventObserver).onChanged(null);

        // check that there were no more changes of this observer:
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mOnClickButtonEventObserver);

        // check that if we re-subscribe this observer on the same LiveData then we do not receive data:
        mSomeFeatureViewModel.getOnClickButtonEvent().observeForever(mOnClickButtonEventObserver);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mOnClickButtonEventObserver);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to test the live data has been observed or not you can use the following test

```
private LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner;
MutableLiveData<Boolean> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData(); //Live data to be observed from viewModel
@Mock
private Lifecycle lifecycle;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        lifecycleOwner = getLifecycleOwner();
PowerMockito.when(lifecycle.getCurrentState()).thenReturn(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    }


 @Test
    public void test() {

        mutableLiveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                assertTrue(aBoolean);
            }
        });
        mutableLiveData.postValue(true);
    }


private LifecycleOwner getLifecycleOwner() {
        return new LifecycleOwner() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
                return lifecycle;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to test whether there was a pop up or not, you can use Robolectric.